# How to make the UI to look the same in landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-orientation

My `LinearLayout` changes with the screen orientation. In portrait mode, it looks perfect:

[image: portrait mode]

But in landscape mode it looks like this:

[image: landscape mode]

How can I fix my UI to look the same on both modes?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"    
            android:src="@drawable/amlet1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"  
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"    
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/lnch1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth3"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"   
            android:src="@drawable/supper" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:text="Breakfast" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="35dp"      
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"   
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:text="Lunch" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:text="Supper" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please indent your code. Its unreadable.

Comment: i paste my images of potrail and landscape above see url

Comment: Please note, your question had grammar issues and spelling mistakes.

Comment: Did you fix your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two different layouts, one for Portrait mode and one for landscape mode. That will solve your problem.

```
Keep your
1. portrait mode layout in res/layout folder and
2. landscape mode layout in res/layout-land folder.
```

Android will take the appropriate layout based on your orientation.

*EDIT : single layout* **

If you want to use single layout for portrait and landscape orientation then following should help you

I have used `android:weightsum` and `android:layout_weight` to make it look proper.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfourth1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"            
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfourth2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfourth3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"  
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"        
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtfth1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:text="Breakfast" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtfth2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"   
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:text="Lunch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtfth3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"  
        android:text="Supper" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how? to create two diffrent layout??

Comment: 2 layouts for solving a simple problem is bad advice. Very soon our dude will need to create *2 layout files. And then for all resolutions. Really bad advice.

Comment: Create a layout-land directory in res folder and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

Comment: is there no any solution for my xml code to fit both resulotion

Comment: @taxeeta, I am suggesting for this particular screen only. The question does not mention about all the screens. Also the person who asked the question did not say anything about using same layout.

Comment: Come on, this can be fixed by a simple center, for 1 line of code fix you are suggesting a full copy of a layout file. No way. Do you know that its possible to develop app's with just 1 layout file and a few extra copies of drawables ?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 LinearLayouts, 1 outer and 2 inner. On the inner layouts put this `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`. This should center both.

Also the fact that you think your portrait works is **incorrect**. Notice the white space on the right hand side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/amlet1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lnch1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgfourth3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/supper" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/border4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Breakfast" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="35dp"
            android:text="Lunch" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfth3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:text="Supper" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes ur right how do i fixed this issue to show same on both orientation

Comment: to fix it, you need to add `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" to your inner layouts, just like it says in the answer. I have also added your own code back. I hope you have no more confusion.

Comment: I missed putting the center_horizontal on your first linearlayout. Please read the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing taxeeta's answer, just add the `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` for both your inner LinearLayout tags.

Comment: Although that is exactly what I have been saying, since you are new and have a correct answer. So upvote.

Comment: @taxeeta, I know that's what you've been saying, I just complemented because it was missing in your answer. You just added the layout_gravity property on the second LinearLayout. I didn't mean your answer was wrong. Sorry if it looked like it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these lines:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfourth1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:src="@drawable/amlet1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfourth2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/lnch1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfourth3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:src="@drawable/supper" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Mostly you should think that you fill the screen and then divide it according to your needs, So it'll fit on landscape, or on portrait, or even with different densities.
And i would also suggest you to put your image's height into differen density dimens' folder, so it can be variety as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put android:layout-weight="33"
this will give 33% space to all three elements and will fit to any resolution in any orientation